# Does Workflow 4.5 require SQL Server for persisting state?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4.5

I'm reading "Pro WF 4.5" published by APress, which seems to say unequivocally that in order to persist state in a long-running workflow after a server crash/shutdown (anything that'd clear memory), a SQL Server back-end is required for persistence.

A lot of the MSDN stuff I see online seems to contradict this.  For example, the article linked below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851337.aspx

What is the real scoop, from someone actually using WF?  TIA.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in Instance Store for SQL Server (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.durableinstancing.sqlworkflowinstancestore(v=vs.110).aspx) but there is nothing stopping you creating your own - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829481(v=vs.110).aspx

That way you could use any persistence you like.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for the reply.  What I really want is a "hands off" approach.  I want to know the store is there and working, but I don't want to have to configure it, extend it, etc.  Basically just want to know my long-running workflows are going to be persisted if the system is rebooted underneath them.  The link you sent me is a good description of a persistence store class, but still leaves me wondering what WF does for me if I don't want to implement anything extra.  I really want to concentrate on developing my workflow if possible, and would like to leave persisting it to WF (?)

Comment: It isn't any extra work just to get the workflow storing and rehydrating, it does most of its self, you should check out these samples - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback Kevin.  WF seems useful but finding documentation has been a bit difficult, and sometimes what I find is not extremely clear.  For example, the MSDN article you referenced in your initial reply (on the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore class) implies that the class is just there to allow a *programmer* to persist the info, and seems to require specific calls to set up (as in, it doesn't happen automatically).

Comment: I think its because Microsoft try to push it to host it as their in their own service.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing your own implementation for durable instance on WF can be done. My experience is that it is difficult to do. I ended up with a provider created by Devart. They created a provider for Oracle databases. You can find more information here https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/WorkflowInstanceStore.html

Comment: Thanks wkalter.  Implementing my own really isn't a goal.  We are hoping to have persistence despite system failures WITHOUT having to do any extra work on our own.  The book I mentioned in my OP seems to hint we're in for some scary configuration, SQL Server work, possibly even some coding, to get persistence.  Other online reading I've done hints we don't get involved at all, that the SQL Server persistence is all part of WF 4.5.  Trying to find out which is true, or if truth lies somewhere in the middle.